# Cypress seems to restart the test after cy.visit

Tags: cypress

I've got the following test using cypress:

```
// myTest.spec.ts

console.log("the test is starting");
describe("My Test Describe", () => {
  const testEmail = makeRandomEmail();
  console.log("test email", testEmail);

  it("should set up the profile", () => {
    // setupProfile just makes some requests and returns a promise
    cy.wrap(setupProfile(testEmail), {
      timeout: 15000,
    });
  });

  it("should test the thing", () => {
    // makeAppUrl just returns a string
    cy.visit(makeAppURL());
    /* test stuff happens here which relies on the generated testEmail */
  });
});
```

This works fine when I run against my dev env (which has no port in the url since it's on 443).

However, I'm running into a weird scenario where, when I run the tests against my local server (on port 3000), the following happens:

1. it logs `"the test is starting"` and `"test email generatedTestEmail"` in the browser console
2. it runs the `setupProfile` fine and that test passes.
3. Then, it reloads the entire test seemingly and relogs what's in (1) (with a new generated email), but (2) is still shown as passing.
4. It tries to run my `it("should test the thing")` block which fails because now I have a new user test email.

When I switch out only my host to point at my dev env instead of local, it works fine and doesn't reload as described in (3).

Has anyone run into something like this before? Could it be related to the fact that I have the port in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the `baseUrl` configuration. This was pointed to the dev env, and the script to run against local did not override this config as described here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Command-Line

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:
You need to put real baseUrl in configuration file. See example below.

Common problems
baseUrl is not set
Make sure you do not accidentally place the baseUrl or another top-level config variable into the env block. The following configuration is incorrect and WILL NOT WORK:

//DOES NOT WORK

```
{
  "env": {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3030",
    "FOO": "bar"
  }
}
```

Solution: place the baseUrl property at the top level, outside the env object.

//THE CORRECT WAY

```
  {
      "baseUrl": "https://.....",
      "env": {
        "FOO": "bar"
      }
   }
```

Please see here for more details
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Common-problems

Answer (score -1):

I would try and make use of mocha's `before()` functionality, to maintain the same data across all tests in the `describe()` block.

```js
// myTest.spec.ts

describe("My Test Describe", () => {
  let testEmail;
  before(() => {
    console.log("the test is starting");
    testEmail = makeRandomEmail();
    console.log("test email", testEmail);
  });

  it("should set up the profile", () => {
    cy.wrap(setupProfile(testEmail), {
      timeout: 15000,
    });
  });

  it("should test the thing", () => {
    cy.visit(makeAppURL());
    /* test stuff happens here which relies on the generated testEmail */
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to fix the issue. It still reloads the entire file, not just the describe block (which is noted by the "the test is starting" logging). Also, the previous method did work when I was not pointed to the local dev server.

Comment: What exactly does the `makeAppURL()` function do? I'm confused as to why changing the url you're navigating to would make the entire page reload, unless maybe `setupProfile` directs you to one environment, and `makeAppURL()` points you to another?

Comment: `makeAppUrl` effectively returns `Cypress.env("host")` with some query params (there url is complex as it has many query params in it). `setupProfile` doesn't actually make use of any cypress commands, it's just plain javascript which makes some http requests to set up the profile for the test.

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to think on it. I don't think having the port in the URL causes issues -- I've been on projects where we swap out the `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` with real urls vs. something like `localhost:8000` and there was no issues like you described.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure why this would be the case, but could you set the email as a Cypress environment variable, and then only re-set it if the value does not exist? And then if you needed to clean it up after, you could use an `after()` block to set the value to an empty string/null/etc.?

Comment: Something like `Cypress.env('testEmail') = Cypress.env('testEmail') ? Cypress.env('testEmail') : makeRandomEmail();`, then `setupProfile(Cypress.env('testEmail'));`, and finally `after(() => { Cypress.env('testEmail') = ''; });`?